# ffmpeg extract the first frame even if I assign other frame?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I have this line of code in Windows Forms c#:

```
string.Format("-i \"{0}\" -s {3} \"{1}\"  -vcodec mjpeg -ss {2} -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo ", input.Path, saveThumbnailTo, secs, imgWidthHeight);
```

the problem is that the code only extracting the first frame whatever I put another frame.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. What are the value for example that you put and what are their types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding -ss {2} twice solved my problem, I added -ss 00:25:00 in the beginning of line and it worked